# How to apply the same condition and operation for each element of an array in C

Tags: c, arrays, conditional-statements

I need to perform the same operation for all the elements of a given array. How can I do that?

In this special case, I need to verify if a specific element (I'll call it by `x`) has, in its adjacent positions, a number that is equal to `x + 1` or `x + 2`. And then I must verify this same condition for all the other elements that are in positions bigger than `array[x]`.

For example, we have the following input:

```
1 2 4 5 6 8 9 12
```

In this case, let `x` be equal to `4`.

The code must do something like that:

```
Is 5 = 4+1 or 4+2? Yes.

Is 6 = 4+1 or 4+2? Yes.

Is 6 = 5+1 or 5+2? Yes.

Is 8 = 5+1 or 5+2? No.

Is 8 = 6+1 or 6+2? Yes.

Is 9 = 6+1 or 6+2? No.

Is 9 = 8+1 or 8+2? Yes.

Is 12 = 8+1 or 8+2? No.

Is 12 = 9+1 or 9+2? No.
```

And then it stops, after doing this verification for all elements bigger than or equal to `x`. And then the code must show on the console all the `yes` cases.

I can do the operation I want for `x`, but I have no idea how to do for the elements bigger than x. I would like a few ideas.

I have tried this until now in C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int next_two_positions(int i, int x) {
    if((i == x - 1) || (i == x + 1) || (i == x - 2) || (i == x + 2)){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

int main(){
    int i, number, array[15];
    printf("Write all the elements of the array:\n");
    for(i=1; i<=15; i++){
        scanf("%d", &array[i]);
    }
    printf("Choose the number you want:\n");
    scanf("%d", &number);

    for(i=number; i<=15; i++){
        if(next_two_positions(i, number)){
            printf("%d ", array[i]);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why is your `for` loop going up to 25 if the array is only 15 elements long?

Comment: `array[15]` means you must start index loop at 0 and end at 14.

Comment: I accidentally typed the wrong number. You are right. It should go up to 15.

Comment: The program accepts 15 elements but you've given only 8 in the example.

Comment: I edited the question. Now it's up to 15. Thank you!

Comment: Rohan Bari, I only wanted to illustrate what I wanted. But you are right. It should actually have 15 elements in the example.

Comment: `if((i == x - 1) || (i == x + 1) || (i == x - 2) || (i == x + 2))` ==> `if(i>=x-2 && i<=x+2)`

Comment: As mentioned, your loop indices are one-off. Arrays indices are addressed from 0 to arraySize-1. So in your case, `array[15]` is addressed from 0 to 14. In your loop, the first element of the array `(array[0])` is skipped, and when `i==15`, you overwrite the bounds of your array, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). From that moment onward, there's no expectation your program will perform as you intend it to.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: pay particular attention to the Using Arrays section, **VERY IMPORTANT** bullet: https://www.cs.uic.edu/~jbell/CourseNotes/C_Programming/Arrays.html